# How much does the vendor name in arm toolchain matters? Can I treat arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc and arm-oe-linux-gnueabi-gcc as same?

Tags: gcc, arm, toolchain

I am trying to build a huge codes with makefiles previously compiled with arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc. Now my new vendor supplied me new toolchain i.e.arm-oe-linux-gnueabi-gcc. Am I need to use this new toolchain? Or previously build code will work?

Comment: If you use the same compiler for **EVERYTHING**, then it doesn't matter (assuming the compiler produces valid code for your platform).  You will have trouble if you are mixing and matching things.  Even the same GCC version might not be compatible due to configuration.  Ie, Cortex-M thumb2 won't run on some old ARM5 (not ARMv5) system.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/225630/352890) of [dave_alcarin](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/121638/dave-alcarin):

> The naming standard in GNU toolchains is `<target>-<tool>`, for example
>   `arm-oe-linux-gnueabi-gcc` would be the compiler for an ARM
>   architecture, Open Embedded Linux variant, while
>   `arm-oe-linux-gnueabi-as` is the assembler of the same toolchain, and so
>   on.

As such a different compiler (`oe` vs `linux`) could matter. Open Embedded Linux can have a different libraries which are incompatible with `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc` binaries.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, if the system libraries were built as arm-oe-linux-gnueabi, and I just built a new version of gcc as armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf, then executables/libraries compiled with that new gcc will likely not be compatible (unable to safely link against) the system libraries?